# Java calling constructors from constructors - application

Tags: java, constructor, this

I've been studying calling constructors from constructors via "this" keyword.

I've found the following code segment in the book `"Thinking in Java, 4th edition"` by `Bruce Eckel`.

```
public class Flower {
int petalCount = 0;
String s = "Initial value";

Flower(int petalCount) {
    this.petalCount = petalCount;
    System.out.println("Constructor with int arg only; petalCount = " + petalCount);
}

Flower(String s) {
    System.out.println("Constructor with String arg only; s = " + s);
    this.s = s;
}

Flower(int petalCount, String s) {
    this(petalCount); //calls for Flower(int petalCount) constructor
    this.s = s;
    System.out.println("Int and String args")
}

Flower() {
    this(47, "hi"); //calls for Flower(int petalCount, String s) constructor
    System.out.println("Default constructor");
}

public void printPetalCount() {
    System.out.println("petalCount = " + petalCount + ", s = " + s); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flower x = new Flower();
    x.printPetalCount();
}
```

}

I am trying to understand the flow of the code above, so I'm going to write down my understanding on it - feel free to correct it:

1. Create a new object of type Flower via the constructor Flower(). Reference to that object is x.
2. Flower(int petalCount, String s) constructor is called from the Flower() constructor. Pass in 47 and hi as parameters.
3. Call for the Flower(int petalCount) constructor, pass in petalCount which is 47.
4. Assign petalCount local variable to the petalCount instance variable. Print it out.
5. Jump back down to Flower(int petalCount, String s) constructor. Set the s local variable to the s instance field. Print s out.
6. Jump back down to Flower() constructor and continue execution with the next println statement.
7. Continue execution in main() with line x.printPetalCount().
8. Finish execution.

Furthermore, I am interested about the application for calling a constructor from a constructor. Couldn't be the same result (setting petalCount and s instance fields to correspondibg values) just by a single constructor?:

```
Flower(int petalCount, String s) {
    this.petalCount = petalCount;
    this.s = s;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, your image is not available. Secondly, you should be avoiding images where possible anyway because they aren't search engine friendly.

Comment: _I've found this code segment in the book[...]_ __Which code segment?__

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: Also, if he/she wants us to review a program flow diagram, I'm not sure how he/she could have avoided providing an image.  (Although, honestly, he/she seems to have done a great job of avoiding anyone seeing the image).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Student
{
    private int age;

    public Student() {
        this(21);//this calling to below constructor 
    }

    public Student(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```